# Filter keys from objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, filter

My API hands me this array of objects:

```
[
 { id: 5, name: "foo" },
 { id: 7, name: "bar" }
]
```

I would like to filter out the ID keys and achieve this:

```
[5,7]
```

What would be considered best practice in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Just use array.map:

```js
var data = [
 { id: 5, name: "foo" },
 { id: 7, name: "bar" }
];

var res = data.map(({id}) => id);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates. Close-vote them instead.